# How to run a function at the end of pasted data in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet where I paste some data and I want to run a function automatically on pasting data at the end of each column to count the number of cells that have some text and then give that row which contains formula a specific color.
For example, I paste the below data:
[image: Excel File]
And now I want to run a function at the end of each column which will display the count of cells containing 'Error'.
The function for the first column would be `=countif(A2:A9, "Error")`, the function for the second column would be `=countif(B2:B9, "Error")` and so on.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Are you saying both the end row and end column can vary?

Comment: No, just the end row can vary.

Comment: A function cannot alter a cell's properties e.g. colour it. A function returns something. You would want either a procedure (and you would need a way to trigger this) or a table with a some kind of formula and conditional formatting.

Comment: @Doomenik's answer below is halfway there. It will give you the formula part.

Comment: That answer is good but when I paste the data, it covers the total row which has formulas.

Comment: If you are pasting in data, and it is not  a table, and can be pasted anywhere then you will need to specify more info and use VBA.

Comment: seems there might still be a way to add the data to the end even with the total rows. VBA Worksheet_Change sub. I have had to grab the reference from Google's webpage cache as direct link is not responding... [Appending data to Excel table with total row](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?ei=ovkwWtfXE-bBgAa9ra-QDQ&btnG=Search&q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fexceltables.com%2Fappend-data-with-total-row%2F)

Comment: Answer updated to handle pasting in new rows.

Answer (score 2):

Format a blank table and create a sum row(Click in table -> Tabletools -> Sum row):

[image]

Write in the sum row your formula like: `=countif([Second],"Error")`

Now you can simply copy in your data and it will calculates the occurence in the last row. On pasting the table in, it will move the sum row automaticly downwards.

Comment: I do not want to format table, I mean it should be simple excel gridlines not table.

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani You dont have to write anything in the headline. You can change the Design to simple excel grid lines if you want to. This is the most simple solution which will work ever. Sure you can achieve the same by developing an addon or an macro. There is currently nothing like that out there cause there are enough simple solutions integrated like the table :)

Comment: Then you will need to write a procedure and decide how you will trigger it. Also, update the question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: @Doomenik Is absolutely right that a table is a simple and effective way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Doomenik's answer

**Part 1** Set your data up as a table and insert a total row. ***Adjust the following table name as appropriate.***

[image: Data]

Then insert total row by going into the design tab, which appears when you are inside the table range, and checking the `Total Row` box

[image: Total row box]

A total row will appear at the bottom of the table with a dropdown icon

[image: Total row]

Starting with column A you want to select the `COUNTIF` function to apply to the total row which means selecting `More Functions` from the drop down and then typing in `COUNTIF`.

In the box that appears enter the following:

[image: Countif arguments]

Notice that the entire data area of column A in the table is referenced by `[ID]`. This will be automatically entered when you select the data area of the table A column range when specifying the range argument to `COUNTIF` i.e. when selecting as below:

[image: Selecting ID column data range]

The criteria argument is `NA()` for error.

You then drag the formula from column A, in the total row, across to column C and autofill will do the rest.

**Part 2:** Apply conditional formatting to the total row by using

```
 =ISFORMULA(INDIRECT("Table1[#Totals]"))
```

in Excel 2016 or

`=LEFT(FORMULATEXT(INDIRECT("Table1[#Totals]")),8) = "=COUNTIF"`

in earlier versions.

Entering the formula:

[image: Entering formula for conditional formatting rules using format cells using a formula option]

Now, specifying the range to apply to:

I messed around with specifying the last row with

```
=INDIRECT("Table1[#Totals]")
```

Turns out, Excel still converts this to the current last row range e.g.

`=$A$11:$C$11`

And this updates even if i add rows to the table.

**Part 3: Adding new rows by pasting**

Now, how to handle the adding of rows by pasting? Insert the following code by [Zak](https://exceltables.com/append-data-with-total-row/) into the worksheet containing the table.

Then paste the new rows into the first column of the totals row and it will update and shift the totals down.

```
Option Explicit

 
Private Const SingleRowOnly As Boolean = False
Private Const MaxRowCount As Long = 100
 
 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
    Dim ResizeRange As Range
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Dim TotalsShowing As Boolean
    Dim ExpandTables As Boolean
    Dim RowIndex As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    
    ' Make sure sheet isn't protected
    If Me.ProtectContents Then Exit Sub
 
    ' If already in a table, then exit
    If Not Target.ListObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 
    ' Make sure only one row is being changed
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 
    ' Make sure we're not in row 1
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
 
    ' Make sure we're in the row right under the Totals row
    If Target.Offset(-1, 0).ListObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 
    ' Set table
    Set Table = Target.Offset(-1, 0).ListObject
    TotalsShowing = Table.ShowTotals
    ExpandTables = Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange
 
    ' If Totals not showing, exit
    If Not TotalsShowing Then Exit Sub
 
    ' Make sure the selection is a contiguous range
    If Target.Areas.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 
    ' Make sure Target range is within the table columns
    If Target(1, 1).Column < Table.ListColumns(1).Range.Column Then Exit Sub
    If Target(1, Target.Columns.Count).Column > Table.ListColumns(Table.ListColumns.Count).Range.Column Then Exit Sub
 
    ' Prepare to adjust table
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Table.ShowTotals = False
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = True
 
    ' Set the resize range
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Table.Range(1, 1).Offset(Table.Range.Rows.Count + 1).Resize(1, Table.Range.Columns.Count)) > 0 Then
        If Not SingleRowOnly Then
            RowIndex = Target.Row
            RowCount = RowIndex
            Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(Me.Range(Me.Cells(RowCount, Table.Range(1, 1).Column), Me.Cells(RowCount, Table.Range(1, Table.ListColumns.Count).Column))) = 0 Or RowCount - RowIndex > MaxRowCount
                RowCount = RowCount + 1
            Loop
            Set ResizeRange = Table.Range.Resize(Table.Range.Rows.Count + RowCount - RowIndex, Table.Range.Columns.Count)
        Else
            Set ResizeRange = Table.Range.Resize(Table.Range.Rows.Count + 1, Table.Range.Columns.Count)
        End If
    Else
        Set ResizeRange = Table.Range.Resize(Table.Range.Rows.Count + 1, Table.Range.Columns.Count)
    End If
 
    ' Make table adjustment
    Table.Resize ResizeRange
 
    ' Put things back the way we found them
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = ExpandTables
    Table.ShowTotals = TotalsShowing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
 
End Sub
```

Quoting from the link:

> There are two constants declared at the top of this code.
>
> SingleRowOnly. This specifies whether multiple rows should be included
> in appending into the Table, or if only a single row should be.
>
> MaxRowCount. As to not go crazy with appending rows to a Table
> automatically, this is the maximum number of rows to include at any
> one time. If SingleRowOnly is set to True, this constant is moot.

So you can adjust as appropriate.

Comment: Awesome and very well explained. Will delete my answer soon.

Comment: @Doomenik: I think you deserve credit for answering the first part according to the question as specified. I will upvote for that part.

Comment: If tried it and by pasting it did increased it automaticly. Normally the sum row shouldn´t be overwritten as long as it is created with the tabletools and not by hand. Anyway your solution will work also for old versions so its an very good addition.

Comment: @Doomenik I was messing around with pasting and i expected the table to expand as you describe (i actually thought i could paste underneath the total row and it would adjust) but i tried above and below total row and it overwrote so i think i must be doing something stupid. My test table was set up as an Excel table. Anyway, in the meantime the OP has gone AWOL :-)

Comment: Thanks @QHarr for the answer but it still over-writes the total row which contains the formula.

Comment: Not if you have set up as a table and you paste over the totals row, it then shifts down. I check what you are doing against my instructions and see if there are any differences. I have tested this as per my layout.

Answer (score 0):

With Autocomplete feature it should update column references automatically

**EDIT**

If you want to auto-do this, maybe you can try to paste the following formula at the end of your data:

`=COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-8;COLUMN()))):(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN()))); "Error")`

### Explanation

`COUNTIF(range; pattern)`

The range is specified with two `INDIRECT` functions. One *pointing* to the first row, and one *pointing* to the last one (those 8 and 1 respectively).

So the range looks like:

`(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-8;COLUMN()))) : (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))`

**NOTE** that I assumed that you have 8 rows in total, but you can put any other number there

Comment: I know that but I want to run these functions automatically while pasting data ,
how can I achieve that?